matlab Serialport read data size doesn't match the data size from STM32 UART sending
I am using the serialport function in MATLAB to read data from a device with a baud rate of 115200. However, the amount of data read in MATLAB is much lower than expected. For example, over a 1-minute period, I collect 27276 bytes in MATLAB, which translates to about 381.6 Hz. Meanwhile, when using a serial tool (like a serial terminal), I can collect 29702 bytes, which translates to around 495 Hz, much closer to what I expect.
So anybody have some advice?
This is my read code and function processData which I have  %
 function readSensorData(app, src, ~) % 读取数据并将数据放入队列
     while src.NumBytesAvailable >= 5
            
        % currentTime = datetime('now'); % 串口数据到达时记录时间戳
        tic
        frameHeader = read(src, 2, "uint8");
        toc
        if frameHeader(1) == 0x55 && frameHeader(2) == 0xAA
            fun_data = read(src, 2, "uint8");
            len = fun_data(2);
            if src.NumBytesAvailable >= len + 1
                if len ~= 0
                    dataToSend = read(src, len, "uint8");
                    checksum = read(src, 1, "uint8");
                    % 计算校验
                    expectedChecksum = bitcmp(mod(sum([fun_data, dataToSend]), 256), 'uint8');

                    if (checksum == expectedChecksum)
                        app.processData(dataToSend)
                    end
                end
            end
        else
            read(src, 1, 'uint8');
        end
        
    end
        
    end


If you want the maximum throughput from the serial port, I wouldn't do processing in the serial port reading function. I would read as fast as I can from the serial port and put that into a buffer. The processing code should act on the buffer data (read, action, and dequeue/remove packet from buffer), not on the data incoming straight from the serial port.

Thank you so much for your suggestion!  I’ve adopted your approach and completely separated data processing from reception. The data processing is now handled in a new thread, and I’m happy to report that the experimental results show the throughput can now keep up with the data transmission. Thanks again, your advice was really helpful!

Thanks. Happy to have been helpful :) If you want you could write an answer to your own question, showing this new code that solved your problem. It may help someone with a problem similar to yours in the future.

Actually, My read serial code just do one thing, which is read data to buffer

Actually, My read serial code just do two things, which is read data to buffer, and tell the another thread that it is time to process data. Here is my code, hope can help you if you encounter the same problem.
function readSensorData(app, src, ~)
        numBytes = src.NumBytesAvailable;
        % tic
        if numBytes > 0
            newData =  read(src, numBytes, 'uint8');
            app.rawData = [app.rawData; newData'];
            send(app.dataQueue,1)
        end
    end

Which app.rawData has Initialized in setup, and code send(app.dataQueue,1) is tell another thread processing data.
